# My app functionality is lost on some devices

Tags: android, assets, jxl

My code below works perfectly on the emulator as well as on some devices .e.g. LG and ZTE devices work 100%. However, on most other devices like Samsung and Huawei, the POI's which I need to plot is not working. Everything else works including the network measurements through the phonestatelistener. On teh non-functional devices, the app opens an displays the Google Map with with no POI's shown. I have tried calling the makeSite() method in different places and it makes no difference.

Any ideas on what I am doing incorrectly. I am new to Android coding so am lost at this stage:

```
enter code here@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    requestforPermission();
    psListener = new myPhoneStateListener();
    telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    telephonyManager.listen(psListener, myPhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS);


    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


}

public void makeSite() throws IOException, BiffException {

    double latitude;
    double longitude;


    try {

        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
        InputStream inputStream = assetManager.open("NewFile.xls");
        Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(inputStream);
        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(0);

        for (int Row = 1; Row < 5010; Row++) {

            Cell siteNameCell = sheet.getCell(0, Row);
            Cell latitudeCell = sheet.getCell(1, Row);
            Cell longitudeCell = sheet.getCell(2, Row);
            Cell siteRevCellH = sheet.getCell(4, Row);
            Cell siteRevCellA = sheet.getCell(5, Row);
            Cell siteRevCellB = sheet.getCell(6, Row);
            Cell siteRevCellU = sheet.getCell(7, Row);


            latitude = Double.parseDouble(latitudeCell.getContents());
            longitude = Double.parseDouble(longitudeCell.getContents());
            siteName = siteNameCell.getContents();
            siteRevH = java.lang.Boolean.parseBoolean(siteRevCellH.getContents());
            siteRevA = java.lang.Boolean.parseBoolean(siteRevCellA.getContents());
            siteRevB = java.lang.Boolean.parseBoolean(siteRevCellB.getContents());
            siteRevU = java.lang.Boolean.parseBoolean(siteRevCellU.getContents());

            towerLatLong = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);


            if (siteRevH == true) {
                siteHigh(towerLatLong, siteName);

            } else if (siteRevA == true) {
                siteAbove(towerLatLong, siteName);
            } else if (siteRevB == true) {
                siteBelow(towerLatLong, siteName);
            } else if (siteRevU == true) {
                positionSite(towerLatLong, siteName, siteChurn);

            }


        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }


}


public void positionSite(LatLng towerLatLong, String siteName, String siteChurn) {
    MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromAsset("ctower1.png"))
            .title(siteName)
            .position(towerLatLong);


    mMap.addMarker(options);

}

public void siteHigh(LatLng towerLatLong, String siteName) {
    MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromAsset("ctower1.png"))
            .title(siteName)
            .position(towerLatLong);
    mMap.addMarker(options);


}

public void siteAbove(LatLng towerLatLong, String siteName) {
    MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromAsset("ctower1.png"))
            .title(siteName)
            .position(towerLatLong);
    mMap.addMarker(options);


}

public void siteBelow(LatLng towerLatLong, String siteName) {
    MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromAsset("ctower1.png"))
            .title(siteName)
            .position(towerLatLong);
    mMap.addMarker(options);


}


@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    try {
        makeSite();
        LatLng site = towerLatLong;
        String name = siteName;
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(site));
        //mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom((site), 16.0f));
        setUpMap();


    } catch (Exception e) {
        toast = Toast.makeText(this, "caught :" + e.getMessage(), toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }
}

public void setUpMap() throws IOException, BiffException {

    UiSettings Ui;
    Ui = mMap.getUiSettings();
    Ui.setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    Ui.setCompassEnabled(true);
    Ui.setAllGesturesEnabled(true);
    mMap.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
    mMap.setMapType(mMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    mMap.setPadding(0, 70, 0, 0);
    //makeSite();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        } else {

        }
    } else {
    }
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
}

@TargetApi(24)
public void requestforPermission() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, CODE_ACCESS_COARSE);


    }

}










public class myPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {

    public int netId;
    public int netId2;
    public int netId3;
    public int netId4;
    public int netId5;
    public int netId6;
    public double netId7;
    public int NetType;



    @Override
    public void onSignalStrengthsChanged(SignalStrength signalStrength) {
        super.onSignalStrengthsChanged(signalStrength);
        NetType = telephonyManager.getNetworkType();

        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        List<CellInfo> cellInfo = telephonyManager.getAllCellInfo();
        if (cellInfo != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < cellInfo.size(); i++) {
                if (cellInfo.get(i).isRegistered()) {

                    if (cellInfo.get(i) instanceof CellInfoWcdma) {
                        CellInfoWcdma cellInfoWcdma = (CellInfoWcdma) telephonyManager.getAllCellInfo().get(0);
                        CellSignalStrengthWcdma cellSignalStrengthWcdma = cellInfoWcdma.getCellSignalStrength();
                        CellIdentityWcdma cellIdentityWcdma = cellInfoWcdma.getCellIdentity();

                        netId3 = cellSignalStrengthWcdma.getAsuLevel();
                        netId2 = netId3 - 116;
                        netId = cellIdentityWcdma.getCid() & 0xffff;
                        netId4 = cellIdentityWcdma.getLac();


                    } else if (cellInfo.get(i) instanceof CellInfoGsm) {

                        CellInfoGsm cellInfogsm = (CellInfoGsm) telephonyManager.getAllCellInfo().get(0);
                        CellSignalStrengthGsm cellSignalStrengthGsm = cellInfogsm.getCellSignalStrength();
                        CellIdentityGsm cellIdentityGsm = cellInfogsm.getCellIdentity();

                        netId = cellIdentityGsm.getCid() & 0xffff;
                        netId2 = (2 * netId3) - 113;
                        netId3 = cellSignalStrengthGsm.getAsuLevel();
                        netId4 = cellIdentityGsm.getLac();

                    } else if (cellInfo.get(i) instanceof CellInfoLte) {

                        CellInfoLte cellInfoLte = (CellInfoLte) telephonyManager.getAllCellInfo().get(0);
                        CellSignalStrengthLte cellSignalStrengthLte = cellInfoLte.getCellSignalStrength();
                        CellIdentityLte cellIdentityLte = cellInfoLte.getCellIdentity();

                        netId = cellIdentityLte.getCi() / 256;
                        netId3 = cellSignalStrengthLte.getAsuLevel();
                        netId2 = netId3 - 140;
                        netId4 = cellIdentityLte.getTac();



                     }

                    }


                }


            }
            if (NetType == 13) {


                setTextViewTextThree(String.valueOf("Node ID:" + (netId)) + "      " + "RSRP:" + (netId2) + "    " + "TAC:" + (netId4));

            } else if (NetType == 3 || NetType == 10 || NetType == 8 || NetType == 15) {
                setTextViewTextThree(String.valueOf("Cell ID:" + (netId)) + "      " + "RSCP:" + (netId2) + "     " + "LAC:" + (netId4));

            } else if (NetType == 2) {
                setTextViewTextThree(String.valueOf("Cell ID:" + (netId)) + "      " + "RxLev:" + (netId2) + "     " + "LAC:" + (netId4));
            }
        }
    }





public void setTextViewTextThree(String s) {

    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.rxLevel)).setText(s);

}



}
```

Comment: Did you made release apk for that.

Comment: No, just a debug apk.

Comment: Release it first and then run every where and then let me know.

Comment: After creating the release, the app now opens without the actual Map being displayed. Everything else is still visible including the zoom buttons and my location button.

Comment: I now have the maps working a again on the release. I learnt today that you need a separate APi key for the release version :). However, it still doe snot plot my POI's from the excel file in ASSET directory.

Comment: Just an update. I have managed to source where the issue seemingly lies. For some reason, the devices on which it is not working do not recognize the lat and long values as they are written currently. My current sample of lat long .e.g. -29.2345 & 31.473. It is only if I change that to a number .e.g. -29 & 31, then the plot works. Any guidance on what I need to do in order for this to work and still plot my POI's accurately?

Comment: I have yet to resolve the issue using and excel file. As a workaround, I have opted to use a CSV file with the information and it works on all devices. Thanks for attempts to assist.